# Track user activity - audit

Tags: setup-audit-log

Is there a way I can track users access to objects and records?

I need the ability to monitor the following:

- Access to record
- Access to report on a record
- File download related to a record

I know that in winter 16 they released the ability to query the SetupAuditTrail object but it doesn't actually give me enough information on what I need.

Is there any thing possible for this?

**EDIT**
I'm currently investigating the EventLogfile.

But I'm not sure if the EventLogfile have any information on the records accessed, for example if I access any Account record is it tracked? If yes, under which type is this info located.

Comment: There is the new (paid) SFDC feature - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2014/10/meet-product-manager-adam-torman-event-log-files.html and there are vendor solutions as well https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5YHjEAN

Comment: @crop1645 Any idea how much is it to activate that feature?

Comment: You need Event Monitoring and it's not the cheapest SFDC feature. Once you have it, you call a rest api to get a huge dump of all the data. You have to absorb that somewhere outside of Salesforce and extract all that data out into a table structure which you could then filter and load back into Salesforce custom object given you have the space for it. Or you can manage it completely outside of SF and keep it in like a SQL table and report off it that way. Really depends how you want to do it and what tools you already have.

Comment: No idea - contact your salesforce salesperson - will depend on org type; wouldn't surprise me if it is a % of your annual subscription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Event Logs to monitor a range of [event types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#event-types), including:

- [Asynchronous Report Run](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#async-report)

  > "Asynchronous Report Run events are created for reporting requests that are scheduled. This category includes dashboard refreshes, asynchronous reports, schedule reports, and analytics snapshots."
- [Content Distribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#content-distribution)

  > "Content Distribution events contain information about content distributions and deliveries to users."
- [Content Transfer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#content-transfer)

  > Content Transfer events contain information about content transfer events, such as downloads, uploads, and previews.
- [Document Attachment Downloads](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#document-attachment-downloads)

  > Document Attachment Downloads events contain details of document and attachment downloads.
- [Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#report)

  > Report events contain information about what happened when a user ran a report.
- [Report Export](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#report-export)

  > Report Export events contain details about reports that a user exported.
- [UI Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#ui-tracking)

  > UI Tracking events contain details about user interactions wit the mobile UI.
- [URI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#uri-event)

  > URI events contain details about user interaction with the web browser UI.

From that shortened list I think URI, Report and Document Attachment Download will give you most of the data you want.

Note that outside of a developer edition org the Event Logs are a paid feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the `RecentlyViewed`  object and track some of the information down.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Type from RecentlyViewed
```

But it has couple of limitations, It does not support the following:

- Reports
- KnowledgeArticle
- Article objects

I'm also trying to use the  `SetupAuditTrail` object for any modifications done by the users.